# How can I resolve not found cargo wasm error?

Tags: rust-cargo, wasm-pack

when build contract with RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo wasm, it shows bellow error.

[image: 1]

After installed wasm-pack with cargo install, it still shows this error. How can I fix it?

Comment: john@john-virtual-machine:~/work/rust-wallet$ RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo wasm
error: no such command: `wasm`

 Did you mean `add`?

 View all installed commands with `cargo --list`

Answer (score 3):

Try to install cargo-wasm:

```
 $ cargo install cargo-wasm
```

then

```
$ cargo --list
```

to see if was correctly installed

then setup your project

```
$ cargo setup
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Don't install `cargo-wasm` package for this. Usually we don't use `cargo-wasm` package for `cargo wasm`. `cargo wasm` is an alias for `wasm = "build --release --lib --target wasm32-unknown-unknown"` usually. So do the following.

Create a folder named `.cargo` and a `.cargo/config` file. Then add the following content.

```
[alias]
wasm = "build --release --lib --target wasm32-unknown-unknown"
wasm-debug = "build --lib --target wasm32-unknown-unknown"
```

Then the command `cargo wasm` or `RUSTFLAGS='-C link-arg=-s' cargo wasm` should work as expected.